# Do I need to redesign my application?

Tags: c++, qt

I may be bordering on a discussion type question here so I apologise if the question is not specific enough.

I would like to know if I my current application design is inherently weak/flawed. My background is C so I am not using clever c++ patterns to their fullest extent, of this I am sure.

My application is similar to a 3D modelling package, without geometry creation (e.g setting up animations using existing models). The user imports a geometry and can set various parameters on pre existing geometry, and there are time dependent values that relate to the whole system. The output is a text file to be processed by another application.

I am using a QTreeview to render a QStandardItemModel. I simply store pointers to my core classes in the model's items. These have specific UI for each class type, and are all descended from a common base class. They all have a QWidget which is their "mainwidget"

When the user clicks on part of the treeview, the stored class is retrieved and its mainwidget is displayed on a pane on the UI. So - treeview on the left, pane to the right with the current item's contents, and a 3D view showing the geometry.

Most of my data is stored in the classes UI elements themselves; I don't have a central database which stores anything, and when it's time to save the project, I traverse the tree and let every item write itself to a QSettings file. This feels quite naive but it does work, and the reverse happens on project load. The project class generates new classes based on the type information in the settings file and they then read the contents out of the file themselves.

Similarly when writing the output file, each item knows how to write itself and does so. Where other classes can influence the output of others (for example, start and end times), higher level classes process the children and will set start and end times based on the order and duration of each child.

Should I be storing more data in the QStandardItemModel itself, or defining my own model perhaps? Does it sound like I have set myself up for future problems?

At the moment I have modified this system a couple of times to provide customised applications, but I am about to try and make it more generic. I welcome suggestions for improving my design. Go easy, please!

Comment: So you have a tree of data nodes which are the GUI elements at the same time? ... What are the custom modifications (mentioned in the last paragraph) like?

Comment: you put it more succinctly than I did -  yes you're spot on. The custom modifications tend to be new classes which provide additional functionality (using the 3D modelling analogy, say allowing a camera to rotate around the geometry) or modifying the UI slightly to tailor it to a particular application. I can subclass quite easily to do that side, and the new behaviour drops in pretty easily.

Comment: Do you have a UML diagram of the parts of your design in question?

Comment: afraid not to the UML diagram

Comment: This looks like a work for Composite design pattern.

Comment: Then, because I do not want to risk having misread your design description, only a very general advice, motivated by you mentioning "c++ patterns. [Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) is a must read; and what you may especially find useful with regard to separating model from GUI are the (creational) Singleton  and the (structural) Facade Pattern.

Comment: @decltype_auto, I have that book and I suppose I am really asking whether I should separate the model more from the GUI.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, that you may consider a Facade Pattern, and estimate  **yourself** what advantage it would bring you to put stuff behind that facade. If the data in question maps almost one-to-one to individual widgets, that facade would likely be plain overdo, but if there is e.g. a compute kernel to be accessed from several GUI.threads, a facade is a most useful thing - we just don't enough about your app yet to provide "the" ultimate advice, you know.

Comment: @decltype_auto - sound advice. I think I am really checking that it doesn't break an obvious design rule in the broad terms that I've described it. I didn't know which patterns might be appropriate and didn't want to apply some patterns just for the sake of it. I will definitely check out Facade, thanks.

Comment: One of the things I'm just noticing from the way you describe things is that your scene graph seems inseparably tied to the user interface. This may or may not be a problem depending on the scale and lifetime of this project. But typically a 3d animation software of scale would tend to model its scene graph independently of its UI.

Comment: Thanks @Ike, I didn't mention it but the scenegraph is independant. There is a seperate item in the tree that handles the model (i.e. the user imports the model through it, and that then sets up the scene graph). I try to make any interaction with the graphics go through that, and most of the parameter assignment happens on an abstraction of the goemetry (i.e. friendly names given to surfaces/volumes which are mapped in the model item)

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid creating [god objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern#Object-oriented_programming). Split your tasks and duties into smaller chunks. It makes it much easier to maintain and also much easier to extend if you need to.

Your specific use-case would benefit a lot from a more complete use of the [Model-View-Controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller).

What doesn't make sense in your design is that your data objects hold a UI element. Since only one item can be shown in the right pane, this seems like a waste of resources. It makes more sense to have a single object that then gets passed a data object to display.

What I suggest for your program is the following:

1. Splitting your data into classes that only have functions for reporting and modifying values. There should be no knowledge of how to display data or store to a file.
2. Create separate class that handles the reading and writing from a file. If your model is very simple, you could just use single functions to do this using the method shown in the documentation for `QDataStream` or `QTextStream`.
3. Use your `QTreeView` and `QStandardItemModel` as [Adaptor class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) between your data objects and the left pannel.
4. Create a controller class that gets informed by the `QTreeView` if data needs to be displayed in the right panel. The controller will then retrieve the data item and pass it to the right panel in order to be displayed.
5. The right panel should act like another View class with the sole responsibility of graphically displaying the data passed in from the controller class.

One advantage of doing it this way is that, if there are different categories of data that get displayed differently in the right panel, the controller could examine the selected data item, determine what the category is, create a view widget to put in the right panel, and then pass it the data to display.
This pattern is open-ended as far as extendability is concerned because you do not need to change your data classes if you need a new display, you merely need to create a new right-panel widget, and then teach your controller class how to determine when the new view should be used.

Another advantage of this pattern is that you only ever need to have a single widget created to display data in your right panel. If you change your selected item, you can just pass it to the view class that already exists and get it to refresh its display with the newly selected data. You only need to distroy the right-panel view widget if a different category of data object is selected and its data needs to be drawn in a different way. The controller class can determine whether a right-panel view widget can be re-used or whether it needs to be swapped out for a different widget.

Comment: I'm intrigued as to why the data classes shouldn't know how to write themselves to a file - isn't it just creating work for myself in passing values from a data class to another class that needs to know how to write that type of data? I typically have one or two instances of each data type to write.

Comment: That's just a good idea. It's might not be appropriate for your project. The advantage of splitting the two is that the data model should be responsible for modifying and verifying data, whereas the file storage should not have to worry about that. Splitting the responsibility also allows you to substitute a difference class in the future that sends the data over a network instead of storing in a file. This is an example of the Serialiser pattern, which you'll see many examples of around the internet, although I've never seen a formal description of it.